# What type of connector is this? MSA 2040

Tags: hard-drive, sas

This connector is on our newly purchased (and incorrect model) MSA SAN Shelf.

What's the name of the connector?  Some people are referring to it as "SAS 3", but I wasn't aware that there was anything other than the standard SAS connectors that most Dell PERC or HP Pxxx Cards use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know specifically what the name of that connector that is, but the photo is of a server *midplane*, and those connectors are probably hot-swap capable cage connectors which interface with a multi-drive daughterboard (where the SAS/SATA connector would be) inside the cage: the cage is akin to a PCIe card with drive ports, and what you depict is akin to the PCIe connectors.

There are tons of images online that look like what you depict here if you google "HP 60-00000213-03 DHS Neptune Mid-plane hard drive"

Comment: Yes this is a midplane/backplane of the SAN shelf, these are the connectors in the back.  My boss is saying that they are SAS-3 Connectors, but I've never actually heard of that connector, and when I google "SAS-3 connectors" I do NOT find images of this connector.

Comment: If that is a msa 2040, and all those devices quote 4 ports per controller, and there are 3 connectors, it seems to me that it cannot be a normal drive connector. A casual perusal of HP cages show standard connectors inside the cage for the drives (and not-drive connectors on the back for the backplane or midplane). It may be proprietary, but again, I expect it is a generalized interface.